# Why I can't access my apache server from another user rather than root user or from outsider the server

Tags: apache, server

[image]

I can't access my apache server from outside the server or from ubuntu user rather than root user.

**Could anyone help me ?**

Comment: You can access the Apache server. You are successfully reading the file from it. The error message says that the user you doesn't have permission to write to the `/var/www/` directory (which is normal, you wouldn't want a regular user to write to the files that make up the web site, that's something that should only happen at deployment time)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `wget` is trying to write the `index.html` file on the `/var/www` directory (your current directory), and your user can't do it (whereas root user can write in this directory).

Comment: i'm wondering why i couldn't access the apache server from outside the server, could u help me ?

Comment: Some parameters on your httdp.conf or in your virtualhost can force your server to listen only 127.0.0.1 and not all IPs